# Does the subscription retry when notification fails?

Tags: fiware-orion

I would like to know about the subscription feature of Orion.

I have two Orions and have registered another Orion "/v2/op/nofity" on one.
However, if there is a momentary communication failure between the two Orions, the notification fails.

I would like to know if the subscription notification will retry?

Answer (score 0):

Orion supports two kind of notification transports: HTTP and MQTT.

Orion doesn't retry notifications in any case, but in the case of MQTT you can specify a QoS value (`qos` field). If the MQTT broker in which you are publishing your notification is properly configured you can have some degree of retrial (but not provided by Orion itself, but by the MQTT broker).

More information on Orion MQTT notifications [here](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/mqtt_notifications.html)